# how could I transfer file from terminal to screen /dev/tty.*(android machine)?

Tags: android, serial-port, adb

I'm developing android set-top box app.
So, I have android box and its adb is REALLY SLOW.

When I have to install .apk file to debug my project, I use `adb connect [ip address]` via wifi and then build & run with Android Studio because the set-top box doesn't have USB port.
But it has serial port so I can connect its shell by `screen /dev/tty.usb-serialblablabla 115200`. when I use that command, I can see exactly same screen as one of `adb shell`.

Its `adb shell`(via wifi) shows very very slow performance.
For example, if I want to run `pm list packages`, I should type 'pm list packages' and wait for **2min**.and then type enter key.(...sigh)

Whereas,Using `screen /dev/tty.*` methods respond promptly.

I don't know where this difference is come from.
but it is not matter of wifi. I checked its speed. it is quite normal.

In this circumstance, I click Run button in Android Studio after `adb connect`.
gradle build takes about 10sec.
upload .apk(10.2mb) takes about **10min** (sigh).

Because `screen ...` way is much faster then `adb connect` way, I want push my `.apk` into device via 'screen'. how can I do? OR is there anything I can do to reduce time for putting `.apk` in android device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should find out why adb transfers take so long. But if you insist on using serial console for uploads instead - you could just use any terminal application with `XMODEM` support on PC side to send the file and `busybox rx -b <filename.apk>` command on android side to save it. Then `pm install <filename.apk>` to install it.

Comment: I tried your answer yesterday, but there was a problem....
Because I use Mac(10.9.4), So ZTerm is the only one option I can use(as far as I know). but I can't figure out how to use it. that was the problem.
Anyway, Thanks for your advice, now I know what to do for solving my problem.

Comment: using zmodem, you can try sz/rz cmd.